# Mapper and service call

Tags: java, object-oriented

I have an entity called `Travel` which has list of `costCenter`. I have created a code for handling CRUD operation for cost centers

```
protected void assignCostCenter(CostCenterDTO costCenterDTO, Travel travel, Long detailsId) throws BusinessException {
    CostCenter costCenter = null;
    if (costCenterDTO.getCostCenters() != null) {
        Center center = commonDao.find(costCenterDTO.getCostCenters().getId());
        costCenter = costCenterDTOMapper.mapToDTO(costCenterDTO.getCostCenters(), travel, detailsId, center);
        if (costCenter != null && !travel.getCostCenters().contains(costCenter)) {
            travel.getCostCenters().add(costCenter);
        }
    } else {
        travel.setCostCenters(travel.getCostCenters().stream().filter(costCenter1 -> !(costCenter1.getDetailId().equals(detailsId))).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

And in the mapper

```
 public CostCenter mapToCostCenter(CostCenterDTO costCenterDTO, Travel travel, Long claimDetail, Center center) throws BusinessException {
        CostCenter costCenter = new CostCenter();
        CostCenter costCenterToUpdate = travel.getCostCenters()
                .stream()
                .filter(costCenter1 -> costCenter1.getDetailId().equals(claimDetail))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
        if (costCenterToUpdate == null) {
            costCenter.setCenter(center);
            costCenter.setTravel(travel);
            costCenter.setDetailId(claimDetail);
        } else {
            costCenterToUpdate.setCenter(center);
            return costCenterToUpdate;
        }
        return costCenter;
    }
```

The functionality is that if new `CostCenter` is assigned, I fetch `Center` from db which was assigned and pass to mapper. In mapper I call `travel.getCostCenters` to see if there is no `costCenter` already assigned with same detail `id` if there is I just update it, if there is no I create new and return, and add to list if doesn't exist. Also if `CostCenterDTO` comes as `null` then I remove from list `costCenter` by `detailId`. My question is how I could refactor it because it doesn't look tidy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the mapper looks ok, but in the cost centers management method, you violate encapsulation by directly manipulating the travel's cost centers list.

I'd rather leave the list management to the travel class:

```
class Travel {
    ...
    void addCostCenter(CostCenter c) {
       ...
    }

    void removeCostCenter(CostCenter c) {
       ...
    }

    boolean containsCostCenter(CostCenter c) {
        ...
    }

    CostCenter findByDetails(Long detailsId) {
        ....
    }
}
```

... and use it like this:

```
protected void assignCostCenter(CostCenterDTO costCenterDTO, Travel travel, Long detailsId) throws BusinessException {
    // note: moved outside declaration of CostCenter to smaller scope
    if (costCenterDTO.getCostCenters() != null) {
        Center center = commonDao.find(costCenterDTO.getCostCenters().getId());
        CostCenter costCenter = costCenterDTOMapper.mapToDTO(costCenterDTO.getCostCenters(), travel, detailsId, center);
        // can costCenterDTOMapper.mapToDTO actually return null? If not, declare it like that and
        // remove the ugly null-check
        if (costCenter != null && !travel.containsCostCenter(costCenter)) {
            // depending on the business logic, you might also consider
            //    travel.addCostCenterIfNotExists(costCenter)
            // and skip the if
            travel.addCostCenter(costCenter);
        }
    } else {
        travel.removeCostCenter(travel.findByDetails(detailsId));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should  move the `contains` and not-null check of the `costCenter` to `Travel` (as in your comment). It's the responibility of  `Travel`  to  keep its own state consistent.